# How can I write IF / ELSE statement equivalent in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to write the equivalent of this in React Native:

```
if(response){
    if(status ==='ERROR'){
        return 'Error'
    }else{
        return 'Response Returned'
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
{
  Object.keys(this.props.myStore.response).length !==0  ? 
  (this.props.myStore.status ==='ERROR') ? 
    <Text>error</Text> : 
    <Text>Response Returned</Text>
}
```

With the code I get errors, I'm new to React Native but have tried variations of the above code, but keep on getting errors. Any further recommendations for improving this code block to "best practice" will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind telling what those error messages say?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are missing the ':' in the outer ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, with the code below:

```
{
      Object.keys(this.props.myStore.response).length ===0 ?
      null : 
      this.props.myStore.status ==='ERROR' ? 
        <Text>error</Text> : 
        <Text>Response Returned</Text>
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**You should try this**

```js
( status === 'ERROR') ? 'Error' : 'Response Returned'
```